# Added empty line Yii textFieldRow

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I created form with yii booster, but added one empty line before textFieldRow label.
There is my code:

```
<div class="form">
    <?php
    $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'location-form',
        'type'=>'horizontal',
    ));?>

    <fieldset>
        <pre><span class="note text-info"><?php echo Yii::t('Site', 'requiredFieldsHint'); ?></span></pre>
            <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($promocode,'code',
            array('maxlength'=>200,'id'=>'code'));?>

        <div id='username_availability_result'></div> 
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
            <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($promocode,'code',array('maxlength'=>200,'id'=>'code'));?>
            <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($promocode,'code',array('maxlength'=>200,'id'=>'code'));?>
            <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($company,'isActive',array('maxlength'=>180,'id'=>'code'));?>
            <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($company,'name',array('maxlength'=>180,'id'=>'code'));?>             
            <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($company,'name',array('maxlength'=>180,'id'=>'code'));?>            
            <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($promocode,'code',array('maxlength'=>200,'id'=>'code'));?>
            <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($promocode,'code',array('maxlength'=>200,'id'=>'code'));?>
    </fieldset>    

    <div class="form-actions">
        <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
            'buttonType'=>'submit', 
            'type'=>'primary', 
            'label'=>Yii::t('actions', 'Submit'),
            'htmlOptions' => array('style'=>'align:center;padding: 4px 58px;'),
        )); 
        ?>
    </div>
   <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

On firebug:

[image]

Comment: there may be some hidden character here. btw, just try to keep them in one php block:

 `<?php
 echo $f...;
 echo $f...;
 echo $f...;
 ?>`

instead of <?php ?> in every line

Comment: I tried this, but result same

Answer (score 0):

```
<fieldset>
            <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($promocode,'code',array('maxlength'=>200,'id'=>'code'));
             echo $form->textFieldRow($promocode,'code',array('maxlength'=>200,'id'=>'code'));
             echo $form->textFieldRow($company,'isActive',array('maxlength'=>180,'id'=>'code'));
             echo $form->textFieldRow($company,'name',array('maxlength'=>180,'id'=>'code'));            
             echo $form->textFieldRow($company,'name',array('maxlength'=>180,'id'=>'code'));            
            echo $form->textFieldRow($promocode,'code',array('maxlength'=>200,'id'=>'code'));
             echo $form->textFieldRow($promocode,'code',array('maxlength'=>200,'id'=>'code')); ?>
    </fieldset>
```

use these change to merge all php in one  PHP block  or for easy HOTFIX use padding in CSS to fix this issue ;)

**OR merge all echo in one echo**

Comment: trying to change label , delete before or after element , at last give you site url if uploaded   , I have to add some css on it to fox

Comment: how can I fix this with css?

Comment: with  a padding or margin to this line , save your form in html and mail it to me I'll see it , my mail is in my profile .

Comment: margin-top:-6px;  added in to that text filed

Comment: thanks, I fixed my problem. Problem is with encoding. I saved  with UTF-8 encode and phpstorm added some characters. I fixed On Phpstorm in context "Remove BOM".